# Как очистить индекс?

Tags: git

Уже задавал вопрос, но ответы не помогли.
Есть директория uploads где лежали файлы свыше 100 мб. Забыл добавить папку в гитигнор. Далее делаю:

```
git add ./server
git commit -m "blabla"
git push
```

Получаю сообщение об отмене так как файл большой. По глупости удаляю директорию вручную. Дальше:

```
git reset
```

Пытаюсь сделать еще один коммит и пуш но опять он грузить большой файл.
Потом делаю:

```
git rm -r --cached ./server
```

Но и это не помогает. Он пишет что все удалил, но кроме папки из-за которой проблемы:

[image: Картинка]

После всех манипуляций все равно получаю:

[image: Картинка]

Загрузка доходит до 100% и дальше опять ошибка: "файл слишком большой"

Comment: Дежурное замечание: текст лучше приводить текстом, а не картинками. И если вопрос является продолжением к предыдущему, то лучше добавить ссылку на него прямо в вопросе...

Answer (score 2):

Нужно удалить файл не только из рабочего каталога, но и из истории коммитов. Сделать это можно, например откатив историю в состоояние до того как большой файл был закоммичен. Если нежелательный коммит последний в текущей ветке, то это можно сделать так:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

Если нужно откатить несколько коммитов, то как-то так:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~3
```

Или можно откатиться прямо к состоянию ветке в удалённом репозитории:

```
git reset --soft origin/master
```

Затем можно сделать `git reset`, `git add` и сделать уже корректные коммиты заново.

---

В качестве альтернативы можно также отредактировать уже сделанные коммиты с помощью `git rebase -i` или `git commit --amend`

---

Cм. подробности в [документации `git-reset`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)